# WiFi scan android javascript

Tags: android, wifi, droidscript

I am trying build an android application that scans for the available access points and saves it in an array. 
I was able to do it using eclipse and android studio but I am unable to do it from droidscript application.
I went through WiFi demos in droidscript to no success.

Just wanna know how can I achieve this using driidscript app.

Comment: You might get some help if you are willing to show that you've tried to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a DroidScript plugin to do that. You should be able to just paste your Java code into the plugin template.  Note: The latest alpha of DroidScript makes it really easy to do that as it can generate the AIDE code for plugins automatically.